# Python: Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python

```
    for key in keys.splitlines():
            
     if key == keyInput:
          request_main()    
     elif not key == keyInput:
       exit_program()
```

Hi, this is the code I am having trouble with; specifically line 7's else if statement, where I am getting an error for Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation. I don't see where it is inconsistent; there's no other errors elsewhere in my whole code for this. I have tried many different spacings for indentations to no avail, thank you.

Comment: `request_main()` and `exit_program()` should have the same indentation.  You can delete all the indentation in front of them, and use either space or tab to make the indentation.（and `elif not key == keyInput:` can be simplified as `else:`）

Comment: its because you're using `tabs` and `spaces` in the indentation, you should only use of of them

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. Deleting all indentations and using tab to make them fixed the errors, thank you!

Comment: In your editor, enable viewing whitespaces and you will be able to catch the problem by yourself